# Python extract data and create data

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, list

I have a txt file of 100GB of data...
Example txt file:

```
(1, 'Dog', '', '3', 'Brown','Female,)
(2, 'Primate', 'Orangutan', '10', 'Orange','Male,)
```

and I want as output:

```
List number: 1               Age: 3
Type: Dog                    Hair Color: Brown
Race: None                   Sex: Female
-------------------------------------------------------
List number: 2               Age: 10
Type: Primate                Hair Color: Orange
Race: Orangutan              Sex: Male
```

How I can make this happen on python???
Thank you I will really Appreciate your Help!!

Comment: Could you share part of the txt file? Are the values separated by a comma (CSV)?

Comment: well the txt file is 10x more complex than what I put, but here is a example : (514, 'Medical terminology, an illustrated guide', '', '', '', 'Barbara Janson Cohen', '2004', '4', 'Lippincott Williams & Wilkins', '', '744', 744, 'English', '147', 'Kolxo3', '7', '9780781762946,0781762944', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'OL9687191M', '', 300, '1', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 12287946, 'djvu', 4, None)    .......... thanks Maze

Comment: Are they in one line or in multiple lines? Could you share a sample of the file in google drive or append the sample to your question?

Comment: they are in multiple lines, is not just 1 line... is more than 200 millions lines.... the data is too big to put it on the internet

Comment: Goddam 100GB of just text. Jees quiz, it would take ages to upload this to a google drive @Maze

Comment: There is someone who answered your question, but I don't think it would work as you have the data inside a txt file and it will read the entire line as an entring string, which will require some pre-processing. Anyhow, you have accepted the answer.

Comment: Maybe you want to explain the purpose of converting `1e+9` lines of text (more or less) into `4e+9` lines of output. It's neither saving space nor reading the output, I suppose. But the purpose could help answering your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`str.ljust()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to get the whitespace after the first item.

```
data = [
    (1, 'Dog', '', '3', 'Brown', 'Female'),
    (2, 'Primate', 'Orangutan', '10', 'Orange', 'Male')
]


first = True
for i, type_, race, age, hair_color, sex in data:
    if not first:
        print("-" * 80)
    else:
        first = False
    print(f"List number: {str(i).ljust(30)}Age: {age or None}")
    print(f"Type: {str(type_ or None).ljust(37)}Hair Color: {hair_color or None}")
    print(f"Race: {str(race or None).ljust(37)}Sex: {sex or None}")
```

Output

```
List number: 1                             Age: 3
Type: Dog                                  Hair Color: Brown
Race: None                                 Sex: Female
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
List number: 2                             Age: 10
Type: Primate                              Hair Color: Orange
Race: Orangutan                            Sex: Male
```

**Why 30 and 37?**
30 was a random value.
`37 = 30 + (len("List number: ") - len("Type: "))` (same for `"Race: "`).

Comment: Thank You Sven Eberth !!!.... I really appreciated :) ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can firstly create a string with template of output and fill it with format function like this one:

```
data = [
    (1, 'Dog', '', '3', 'Brown', 'Female'),
    (2, 'Primate', 'Orangutan', '10', 'Orange', 'Male')
]

template = """List number: {0:<23} Age: {3:<10}
Type: {1:<30} Hair Color: {4:<30}
Race: {2:<30} Sex: {5:<30}
"""

for idx, _ in enumerate(data):
    print('-'*70) if idx > 0 else None
    print(template.format(*_))
```

with context manager:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        data = split_line_to_list(line)
        print('-'*70)
        print(template.format(*data))
```

Comment: Thank You Andy Pavlov !!!.... I really appreciated :) ...

Comment: '''with open('1.txt', 'r') as f:''' Hey Andy, how I can open it from a txt file each line at the time using your code??

Comment: Yes. Use context manager. I write additional code to my reply,

Answer (score 1):

I used the template generated by [@AndyPavlov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025299/andy-pavlov)

```py
import sys
import re

__Animal_attributes__ = {
    'id': int,
    'type': str,
    'race': str,
    'age': int,
    'hair_color': str,
    'sex': str
}

class TxtFileHandler:
    @staticmethod
    def parse(data):
        if len(data.strip()) > 0:
            return [a.strip() for a in re.sub(re.compile(r'[\(\)\r\n\']'), '', data).split(',')]
        else:
            raise Exception(f'Error parsing data [{data}]')

    @staticmethod
    def read(filename:str, fn, data: list = list()):
        try:
            file = open(filename, 'r')
        except OSError as e:
            print(e)
        with file:
            for line in file:
                try:
                    data.append(fn(line))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Error executing callback [{fn}] with data [{line}]. Received exception: {e}')
            return data

class Animal:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for idx, (attribute, parsing_fn) in enumerate(__Animal_attributes__.items()):
            setattr(self, attribute, parsing_fn(args[idx]))

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        template = """List number: {0:<23} Age: {3:<10}
Type: {1:<30} Hair Color: {4:<30}
Race: {2:<30} Sex: {5:<30}"""
        return template.format(*[getattr(animal, a) for a in __Animal_attributes__.keys()])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    animals = TxtFileHandler.read(filename, lambda line: Animal(*TxtFileHandler.parse(line)))
    for idx, animal in enumerate(animals):
        print(animal, f'\n{"-"*70 if idx < len(animals)-1 else ""}')
```

Comment: Thank You loko !!!.... I really appreciated :) ... the filename is '1.txt'  .... but everytime I run the code it shows this: data = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Oh, you have to add the parameter when running the script. For example `python animals.py ./data/animals`.

Comment: thank you very much loko :) .... for me it work putting in line 32 just this: data = '1.txt'  .... instead of data = sys.argv[1]   ......... thank you very much, I really APPRECIATED !!! :)

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. I fixed the code to handle empty lines, just in case. Readability could be improved by changing the lambda for a function object though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (*You can try using `None` instead of empty string*):

```py
import ast
fileBuffer = open('fileName.text', 'r')

for line in fileBuffer.readlines():
    data = ast.literal_eval(line.strip())
    print(f'Line number:{line[0]}\tAge:{line[3]}')
    print(f'Type:{line[1]}\tHair Color:{line[4]}')
    print(f'Race:{line[2]}\tSex:{line[-1]}')
    print('-------------------------------------------------------')
```